# offical mongo docker image cannot use custom file via volumen

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am trying simply to use mongo with custom configuration file placed in my host machine. I obtain 100 error code, I tested this in debian 10 and on a windows 10 machine (docker desktop). I think that its a permission issue, may be mongo has not permission to use those files.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.7"

services:

  mongod:
    image: mongo:4.1.13
#    restart: always
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
    volumes:
      - ./config/mongo/mongod.conf:/etc/mongod.conf
      - ./data/mongo:/data/db
#      - ./log/mongo:/var/log/mongodb
    entrypoint: ["mongod","--config","/etc/mongod.conf","--verbose"]
```

mongod.conf (default)

```
# mongod.conf

# for documentation of all options, see:
#   http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/

# Where and how to store data.
storage:
  dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb
  journal:
    enabled: true
#  engine:
#  mmapv1:
#  wiredTiger:

# where to write logging data.
systemLog:
  destination: file
  logAppend: true
  path: /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log

# network interfaces
net:
  port: 27017
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1


# how the process runs
processManagement:
  timeZoneInfo: /usr/share/zoneinfo

#security:

#operationProfiling:

#replication:

#sharding:

## Enterprise-Only Options:

#auditLog:

#snmp:
```

Error:

[image]

This, this image does not create a log file under /var/log/mongodb.

Answer (score 1):

Your `docker-compose.yml` and `mongod.conf` has inconsistent options:

`docker-compose.yml` specifies `/data/db` as a folder for DB files, but `mongod.conf` tries to use `dbPath: /var/lib/mongodb` (which is missing in your container). Fix your `mongod.conf` to point to `/data/db/` folder and it should fix your error.

To debug such kind of error, your can run your image (mongo) by hand (`docker run ...`) with `bash`, instead of using `docker-compose` and you will be able to see all error in logs.